# faq about Java8 java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm

Tags: java, swing, lambda, jvm, java-8

Trying to shrink the size of jre for a java swing program. Using the following command to print all the loaded class:

```
java -jar -verbose:class demo.jar >>class.txt
```

In the result,i see something which i donot know where it is.I am using jre8 and following is:

```
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/603742814 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/1067040082 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI/1325547227 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]
[Loaded java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NFI/980546781 from java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm]
```

what does java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$NFI and java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH and java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$LFI stands for? I check the classes in rt.jar.It does not have these class or innerclass.
Any idea? thanks!

Comment: *"Trying to shrink the size of jre for a java swing program."* I'm pretty sure that would violate the distribution licence..

Comment: i am not mean to sell it,just for test.

Comment: *"just for test."*  I'd say it was a completely pointless test (not that I believe you - mostly for the fact that it is pointless).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: [*Compact Profiles*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/) may be apropos.

Comment: @trashgod We live, we learn.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson In fact,this is some kind of homework.I do not know why the teacher give this task either.It seem like pointless in jdk8,but i will try it in jdk7 environment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct about the potential violation in previous versions; the exercise may be intended to identify new features, a task that plagues & inspires even experienced developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As documented [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/invoke/LambdaForm.java), these nested classes are used in the representation of [lambda forms](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/160), which are used in the implementation and optimization of method handles (no relation to [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).) If you want to shrink the size of the deployed JRE for a Java <strike>Swing</strike> program, use [*Compact Profiles*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/), which "enable reduced memory footprint for applications that do not require the entire Java platform."

Addendum: As shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/compactprofiles.html), Swing is available only with the full API.